# Android AlertDialog - Header background color

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to change the background color of the "header" (top section) of an AlertDialog. I managed to change the color of the title but I can't find how you change the background color of its container. Is it possible? Any suggestions?

This is what I have so far.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogTheme</item>
</style>
```

**another_file_with_styles.xml**

```
<style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/success_color</item>
</style>
```

**a method in a class does this**

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setTitle(searchCriteria.getName());
builder.setItems(items, clickListener);

AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();

// Eventually I'll do this to change the color of the divider
// int titleDividerId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("titleDivider", "id", "android");
// View titleDivider = alert.findViewById(titleDividerId);
//
// if (titleDivider != null) {
// titleDivider.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.accent_color));
//}
```

I was trying to follow [this tutorial](http://blog.supenta.com/2014/07/02/how-to-style-alertdialogs-like-a-pro/), but it doesn't explain how to change the background color of the window.

EDIT: just to be clear, the arrow is pointing to the gray/white background color (not to the title [Make and Model])

[image]

Comment: Scroll a bit down in the tutorial you posted.

**Part 5: style the background**
I want a red background behind my title.

Answer (score 5):

You can set the background color of the title using a custom title view.

Creat the custom title view and define the background color:

*res / layout / custom_title.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Set the custom title view:

```
View customTitleView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_title, null);
TextView title = (TextView) customTitleView.findViewById(R.id.title);
title.setText("TITLE");

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setItems(items, clickListener);
builder.setCustomTitle(customTitleView);

AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```